# AS3 parseInt() method limitations

Tags: actionscript-3, parseint

I have this issue in converting a HEX string to Number in as3

I have a value
str = "24421bff100317"; decimal value = 10205787172373271

but when I parseInt it I get
parseInt(str, 16) = 10205787172373272

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like adding one ("24421bff100318") works fine. I have to assume that means this is a case of precision error.

Because there are only a finite amount of numbers that can be represented with the memory available, there will be times that the computer is estimating. This is common when working with decimals and very large numbers. It's visible, for example, in this snippet where apparently the computer can't add basic decimals:

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i+=0.2){
    trace(i);
}
```

There are a few workarounds if accuracy at this level is critical, namely using datatypes that store more information ("long" instead of "int" in Java - I believe "Number" might work in AS3 but I have not tested it for your scenario) or if that fails, breaking the numbers down into smaller parts and adding them together.

For further reading to understand this topic (since I do think it's fascinating), look up "precision errors" and "data types".

Comment: Thanks @Thomas very nice and descriptive answer I am actually storing this into a Number after parsing it but still no use. ow I will look into splitting and adding up later

Comment: Okay, good luck with that. If this helped, do please give it a vote - I'm trying to get enough karma to comment on other questions!